# add a line and characters after last match(es)

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have a file that I need to append a line to (and a couple of characters) after the last match of the beginning of a line (the 3 digit number). The data are grouped by (many) gene number (122,239,...), and each gene may have variable numbers of individuals.

```
cat test

122_mex1 TGCAGGC
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex3 TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGCA
...
567_can4 TGCAAAT
```

The output should look like this:

```
cat output

122_mex1 TGCAGGC
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex3 TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
//|1
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGCA
//|2

etc.
```

How then to find the last match of each gene number that starts each line and append a line with some characters, counting up (1, 2, 3, etc)?

I have found a way to append a line after a provided match (e.g. 122)

```
awk '/122/{seen++} seen && !/122/{print "//|1"; seen=0} 1' test
```

but id like to append for all gene numbers (122, 239, 455, 234, etc), looping over genes and appending each successive gene number on the following line "//i".

Any thoughts on how to start this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
$ awk -F_ 'NR>1 && last!=$1{print "//|"++i}{last=$1}1' test
122_mex1 TGCAGGC
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex3 TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
//|1
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGCA
//|2
...
//|3
567_can4 TGCAAAT
```

To save the results use shell redirection:

```
$ awk -F_ 'NR>1 && last!=$1{print "//|"++i}{last=$1}1' test > output
```

Comment: Nicely done; to also terminate the _last_ block, you'll probably want to append `END{print "//|"++i}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F_ 'p!=""{p=$1;next} p != $1 {p=$1; print "//|" ++i} 1; END{print "//|" ++i}' test
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex3 TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
//|1
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGCA
//|2
```

**Explanation:**

```
-F_                     # set field separator as _
p!=""{p=$1;next}        # first time if p is not set, set p=$1 and move to next line
p != $1                 # if 1st field is != previous value of 1st field
{p=$1; print "//|" ++i} # set p=$1 and print divider line with an incrementing var
1;                      # default action to print each record
END{print "//|" ++i}    # END block to print divider line last time
```

Comment: very nice! Could you explain a bit about each component? This is different from how I was going to approach it.  Im not sure I understand all of it...

Comment: `!p` should really be `p!=""` in case the real data has `000_mex1`.